# XCM's Origin Kinds, what privilege does XCM origin does not have?

Tags: xcm

Different origin serve different purpose and certain privileges, care to list the privileges per OriginKind.

And yes the documentation is not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

I believe this [doc](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/doc/xcm/v2/enum.OriginKind.html) is straightforward:

**Native**

Origin should just be the native dispatch origin representation for the sender in the local runtime framework. **For Cumulus/Frame chains this is the Parachain or Relay origin if coming from a chain**, though there may be others if the MultiLocation XCM origin has a primary/native dispatch origin form.

**SovereignAccount**

Origin should just be the standard account-based origin with the sovereign account of the sender. **For Cumulus/Frame chains, this is the Signed origin**.

**Superuser**

Origin should be the super-user. **For Cumulus/Frame chains, this is the Root origin**. This will not usually be an available option.

**Xcm**

Origin should be interpreted as an XCM native origin and the MultiLocation should be encoded directly in the dispatch origin unchanged. **For Cumulus/Frame chains, this will be the pallet_xcm::Origin::Xcm type**.

If you have a more specific question, please ask.

**Resources**

- https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/doc/xcm/v2/enum.OriginKind.html
- https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/executor_config/index.html#originconverter